# 3-colouring with a bounded amount of colors

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, runtime-analysis, discrete-mathematics, algorithm-design

The topic of 3-colouring is often talked about, but what happens if we limit the amount of times we can use one color? Take a graph $G=(V,E)$ with $k$ being the number of vertices, is it possible for a polynomial time algorithm to check if the graph $G$ admits a 3-colouring where the first color is only used at most $k$ times or where any color is used at most $k$ times?

Comment: The first variant seems more interested. One can ask whether 3-coloring is fixed-parameter tractable when parametrized by the size of the smallest color class. That is, is there a function $f(k)$ such that one can determine whether a given graph has a 3-coloring in which one the smallest color class contains at most $k$ vertices in time $f(k) \mathit{poly}(n)$? I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the graph has $k$ vertices, any color cannot be used more than $k$ times, so I'm not sure I see the problem here.

If the limitation is an input of the problem, then the problem becomes harder, not easier, so it is still $\mathsf{NP}$-complete.

Comment: The problem is how would you design an algorithm that would verify that a color was or was not used k times in polynomial time

Comment: Just use an array to count the number of times each color is used?

Comment: If you use an array to verify, how would you go about vertex to vertex in order to assure you are in polynomial time for very big k?

Comment: $k$ is an input of the problem since it is the number of vertices. An array of length $k$ is in polynomial size in $k$, so what is the problem?

Comment: How would you traverse the graph in polynomial time to see that there is in fact a maximum of k colors used?

Comment: I give up...$ \, $